# bind param in php for insert query before run execute function

Tags: php, mysqli

I don't get the bind param in php. Why must use bind but not just execute the query directly? is it because the query format is an array?

[image]

Comment: Please copy the actual code in and not just a link to an image with the code.

Comment: @h2ooooooo this is from youtube, no code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use prepared statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988867/when-should-i-use-prepared-statements)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by the **[bind_param()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)** function you're using mysqli extension. There is no clear answer to "Why can't you just execute the query itself?" except this one.

You're not using a simple query in this case, but you are creating a **[prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php)**. Prepared statements as **[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** states are *parameterized* form of queries.

So you can't execute a query which is missing parameters, in this case you're probably executing this query :

```
INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name, bio, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, YOUR_TIME_FUNCTION)
```

As you can notice three parameters are missing, so you can't possibly execute that query in that state. Instead, if you have a static query you can use the **[mysqli_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)** function, which won't accept parameters since it expects an executable query.