# When should I use prepared statements?

Tags: php, security, prepared-statement, sql-injection

Originally I used `mysql_connect` and `mysql_query` to do things. Then I learned of SQL injection, so I am trying to learn how to use prepared statements. I understand how the prepare and execute functions of the PDO class are useful to prevent SQL injection.

Are prepared statements only necessary when a users input is stored into a database? Would it be okay to still use `mysql_num_rows`, since I don't really run the risk of being hacked into by using this function? Or is it more secure to use prepared statements to do this? Should I use prepared statements for everything that involves using MySQL? Why?

Comment: if you can guarantee no part of your codebase ever uses user generated query data, there is very little point. If you have even a single query, there is no point in using two different ways of forming queries. Go with prepared queries for security first, and consistency second.

Comment: You seem to have a slight confusion. First, please [don't use `mysql_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead. Second, `mysql_num_rows` has nothing to do with prepared statements and is not a PDO feature, anyway. You prepare the statement before you run the query, not after it when you want to count rows.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**tl/dr**

#### Always. 100% of the time, use it. Always; and even if you don't need to use it. USE IT STILL.

---

`mysql_*` functions are defunct, so you've got to use [**`PDO`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [**`MySQLi`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php). Either of those 2 will suffice as compatible libraries when using prepared statements.

Adding a variable in your SQL query directly is like leaving your car in a bad neighborhood, unlocked and with the keys in the ignition. You're basically saying, just come on in and take my goodies [image]

You should **never**, and I mean never, put a data variable into SQL.
Unless you want this:

[image: SQL Injection]

> *You should also avoid any vague definitions such as "user input". One cannot strictly define what a "user input" is. Not to mention that any input can contain a silly quote that would break your query. It's not where the data is coming *from* that matters, but where it's coming **to**: any data going to be used in the SQL? Pass it via prepared statement*.

Now into how it works. The way prepared statements work is simple, it sends the **query** and the **data** together, but separate (*if that makes sense haha*) - What I mean is this:

```
Prepared Statements
Query: SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo = ?
Data:  [? = 'a value here']
```

Compared to its predecessor, where you stuffed the query with the data, sending it as a whole - in turn, meaning it was executed as a single transaction - causing SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Given you need to use the following variable in the query,

```
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
```

For PDO, you can use a code like this

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->execute([$name, $value]);
```

For mysqli,

```
$dbh->execute_query("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?,?)", [$name, $value]);
```

---

**More Reading**

- [**How can I prevent SQL-injection in php?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1)
- [**What is SQL-injection? (<sup>*Simple Terms*</sup>)**](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/25710)

Comment: @Darren I want to know if I get this right. Is it necessary to use a prepared statement where there are only fixed values? For example somebody needs to approve or deny a request and the only input that person gets is the choice of 2 buttons approve and deny and each on of the buttons writes different values which is fixed. Do I need to use a prepared statement there? 

**Note:**
That page does not gives the user any possibility for users to input any text.

Comment: @BRoebie It's better to be safe than sorry. Anywhere a user can interact with data being passed through (i.e. forms) should essentially be prepared statements. If you're taking said values from input that's easily modifiable from element inspection/etc, then you could be in a lot of trouble.

Comment: @Darren I agree. I was wondering if I need to use prepared statements if the user could only interact with 2 buttons on the page one would write _request approved_ in the db and the other button would write _request denied_ in the db. (and yes it is a form what I am talking about but all the fields there are readonly fields which can't be modified, only the 2 buttons which I mentioned above with fixed values in the code that are send to the db)

Comment: I know this is very late (painfully so), but I just want to mention that, when talking about 'user input', this means the request that is sent to your page / application, not specifically a webform. Users can do an HTTP request (for instance) directly to your application without ever actually requesting the index (or any other for that matter) page on your website. Please understand how the communication between server and client works because this is CRITICAL 

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR Use prepared statements 100% of the time if your SQL makes use of data or input of any kind**

---

You seem to have a slight confusion. First, please [don't use `mysql_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead. Second, `mysql_num_rows` has nothing to do with prepared statements and is not a PDO feature, anyway. You prepare the statement before you run the query, not after it when you want to count rows.

As for when to prepare statements, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans nailed it in the comments. If you ever, even once, use any data that has ever been touched by a user -- even a supposedly trusted user -- or is generated by any kind of third party or third-party application, including a browser, use prepared statements. Only if 100% of your data is hard-coded can you trust it.

For example, you cannot trust:

- Usernames
- Passwords
- Email addresses
- User comments
- Phone numbers
- Dates
- Search strings
- Browser client strings
- Credit card numbers
- File names for uploads
- And *any* other kind of input created by a user or that a user could manipulate.

You should validate all of these (for example, check that an email address is really an email address) before putting them in a database, of course. But even then, using prepared statements is the safe way to go.

Comment: I get what you are saying. The reason I mentioned that I am using mysql_num_rows is because I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305230/alternative-for-mysql-num-rows-using-pdo
and it seemed kind of pointless. If no user data is being processed then mysql_num_rows should be fine right?

Comment: Yes; as long as you're certain there's no user data, such as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable`, you don't have to use prepared statements. Personally, though, I would recommend always using prepared statements; lots of security flaws get introduced when an old query with no user data gets updated and the programmer forgets to use prepared statements for the new query. That's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a two solution for this-

**01- Use Prepared Statements**

To prevent SQL injections we will have to use something called prepared statements which uses bound parameters. Prepared Statements do not combine variables with SQL strings, so it is not possible for an attacker to modify the SQL statement. Prepared Statements combine the variable with the compiled SQL statement, this means that the SQL and the variables are sent separately and the variables are just interpreted as strings, not part of the SQL statement.

**02- Prepared Statements with mySQLi.**

Using the methods in the steps below, you will not need to use any other SQL injection filtering techniques such as mysql_real_escape_string(). This is because with prepared statements it is not possible to do conventional SQL injection.

eg -

```
$name = $_GET['username'];

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE name=?")) {

    // Bind a variable to the parameter as a string. 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);

    // Execute the statement.
    $stmt->execute();

    // Get the variables from the query.
    $stmt->bind_result($pass);

    // Fetch the data.
    $stmt->fetch();

    // Display the data.
    printf("Password for user %s is %s\n", $name, $pass);

    // Close the prepared statement.
    $stmt->close();

}
```

You can find more about this form - http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-SQL-Injection-in-PHP

Answer (score -1):

`Mysql_*` already has been deprecated so better to switch `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

For prevent sql injection (mysql) :- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

And prepared statements(These are SQL statements that are sent to and parsed by the database server separately from any parameters. ) use on your every user generated query data.

like on posting data you matching/getting records to db with query. so mean when you fire a query with form data.