# Generate JSON with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've a PHP with far too many query (like 20) and each one has a few echo with var. I would like to generate a JSON with those vars.. in a single JSON File.

Example:

```
// QUERY 1

$query = "SELECT * FROM $table1 WHERE DateV = '$dateV' AND StatusV = 'WORKING'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error : $query. " . mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo '&Tvar=' . $row['num'];
echo '&Tvarname=' . $row['name'];


// QUERY 2

$query = "SELECT * FROM $table2 WHERE DateV = '$dateV' AND StatusV = 'WORKINGFAST'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error : $query. " . mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo '&Bvar=' . $row['something'];
echo '&Bvarname=' . $row['something'];
```

and since I need to load that data, from an Desktop AIR App, every 2 seconds from multiples intances I don't wanna overload the MYSQL Server. Anyway, I believe the best thing I can do, it's to generate a single file and load that one as many times as I need.

Thank you!

Comment: does it work if you put all the variables into an array then `json_encode` the array and print it out? why are you printing out a query string?

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking that since I don't know how to do that. That's why I was trying to explain what I've so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your values to an array and use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). If you're worrying about overloading your MySQL server, I can say that this query every 2 seconds is not a problem.

It's a good practice to cache results which doesn't change every few calls. So you can take a look at [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) or just use a simple file cache with [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

You can try it with a code similar to this below:

```
$jsonFile = "my.json";// path to your json file
$timeToCache = 1 * 60;// cache time in seconds

// see if the file exists and if the file is older than the time we want to cache
if( file_exists( $jsonFile ) && ( ( time() - filemtime( $jsonFile ) ) > $timeToCache ) ) {
    $toJson = array();
    // your first query goes here
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $toJson["Tvar"] = $row['num'];
    $toJson["Tvarname"] = $row['name'];

    // your second query goes here
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $toJson["Bvar"] = $row['something'];
    $toJson["Bvarname"] = $row['something'];

    // put your json output to some file
    $jsonOut = json_encode( $toJson );
    file_put_contents( $jsonFile , $jsonOut );
} else {
    $jsonOut = file_get_contents( $jsonFile );
}

echo $jsonOut;
```

And you should also stop using mysql_* functions, because they are deprecated:

> Warning This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed
>   in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be
>   used

Take a look at [Why should I use prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24989031/5297359).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// QUERY 1

$query = "SELECT * FROM $table1 WHERE DateV = '$dateV' AND StatusV = 'WORKING'";
$arrfinal = array();
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error : $query. " . mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);



$arrfinal['first'] = array('Tvar'=>$row['num'], 'Tvarname'=>$row['name']);
// QUERY 2

$query = "SELECT * FROM $table2 WHERE DateV = '$dateV' AND StatusV = 'WORKINGFAST'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error : $query. " . mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$arr = array(
            'Bvar' =>$row['something'],
            'Bvarname' => $row['something']
);
$arrfinal['second'] = $arr;
echo json_encode($arrfinal);
```

Comment: remove the two echo's at the top, leave just the output of `json_encode` so the json string can be consumed

Comment: Yeah, but that would generate multiple arrays, right? If I do that for each Query the last line should be something like  echo json_encode($arr, $arr2, $arr3);

Comment: Then you have to create miltidimention array for this.

Comment: Sorry I just missed those.

Comment: Could you elaborate in multidimention array?

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't noticed that. I'll try it shortly, thanks!