# HTML/PHP code to add numbers to a whole sum

Tags: html, mysql, database, addition, calculator

Lets just say I am keeping track of money. So I have my balance in a mysql database. My balance would be $100

I want to create a html script so when I enter say 50 and hit submit it will change the database value to 150.

I know the basics of how to connect to a mysql and insert and get data from a database, thats no problem I done that many times but instead of hitting submit and having the value change to just 50 how can I code it so it just adds on to the value so it will be 150?

Comment: You can first fetch the value present in the database and simply add the new value with the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$value` contains the number you want to add to the amount.

```
$sql = "UPDATE table_name SET current_balance = current_balance + $value`;
```

Running the query will add `$value` to whatever you had as `current_balance`. You can read up on [prepared statements, SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988867/when-should-i-use-prepared-statements/24989031) etc to make the query I've written more secure.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I never knew that loi

Answer (score 1):

To change balance for specific user your mysql query must be like:

```
UPDATE users SET balance = balance + 50 WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I never knew that loi