# Simple DateTime sql query with php object

Tags: php, mysql

This is my  Query . It does not give result.If i place a quote the query runs. How to place that quote.

```
Select sum(r.views) as sum_views ,r.revenue_date ,
l.lot_id ,l.lot_name,r.type_name 
FROM tbl_revenue_upload r , tbl_lot_details as l
WHERE  AND l.lot_id ='.$search['lot'].' 
And revenue_date >= '.$search['from_date'].'
And revenue_date <= '.$search['to_date'].'
group by r.type_id ,month(revenue_date)
```

Comment: Your query seems to be Incorrect with syntax Errors. There is no condition for checking under WHERE condition :)

Comment: Use prepared statements which will make your life easier.

Comment: Worth having a look at this [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24989031/1620779) answer.

Comment: For goodness sake, please consider using prepared statements.

Comment: I am comfortable using this for goodness sake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'Select sum(r.revenue) as sum_revenue ,sum(r.views) as sum_views ,r.revenue_date ,l.lot_id ,l.lot_name,r.type_name 
                     FROM tbl_revenue_upload r , tbl_lot_details as l
                     WHERE r.video_id = l.video_id AND l.lot_id ='.$search['lot'].' 
                     And revenue_date >= "'.$search['from_date'].'"
                     And revenue_date <= "'.$search['to_date'].'"
                     group by r.type_id ,month(revenue_date)
```

Comment: There is no problem with answering your own question, but please include the details regarding the changes and why you think those changes are relevant.

Comment: And if something starts with an inverted comma, perhaps it should end with one too

Comment: @sjsam  .The error was just too add comma " " and it worked fined

Comment: @priyankasawant  Glad that this works. As I have mentioned in my comment to q, you may use  prepared statements which makes  your life easier.