# How can I style the results of table 2 differently to table 1

Tags: php, sql

The below code works but I want to develop it further by styling the results from the 'sponsor' table differently to the 'photos' table. How can I target it to do so?

```
<?php
$search = $_GET['s'];
$db = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "") or die ("could not connect to mysql");

if ($search) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos
            WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%'
            ORDER BY id DESC";
} else {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM photos
            UNION SELECT * FROM sponsor
            ORDER BY id DESC';
}

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >=1) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo"<a href=".$row['link'].">";
        echo"<div class='img_div'>";
        echo"<div class='white'><img src='images/".$row['image']."'></div>";
        echo"<h2>".$row['title']."</h2>";
        echo"<div class='date'>".$date = date('j F, Y', strtotime($row['date']))."</div>";
        echo"</div>";   
        echo"</a>"; 
}
//continue
}else{
echo "No Results";
}
?>
```

UPDATE: Trying to incorporate the below answer

```
if ($search) {
$sql = "SELECT photos.*, 'photos' AS 'tableName1' FROM photos
        WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%'
        ORDER BY id DESC";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT photos.*, 'photos' AS 'tableName1' FROM photos
        UNION SELECT sponsor.*, 'sponsor' AS 'tableName2' FROM sponsor
        ORDER BY id DESC";
}

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >=1) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo"<a class=\"{$row['tableName1']}\" href=".$row['link'].">";
        echo"<div class='img_div'>";
        echo"<div class='white'><img src='images/".$row['image']."'></div>";
        echo"<h2>".$row['title']."</h2>";
        echo"<div class='date'>".$date = date('j F, Y', strtotime($row['date']))."</div>";
        echo"</div>";   
        echo"</a>";


        echo"<a class=\"{$row['tableName2']}\" href=".$row['link'].">";
        echo"<div class='img_div2'>";
        echo"<div class='white2'><img src='images/".$row['image']."'></div>";
        echo"<h2 class='sponsor'>".$row['title']."</h2>";
        echo"</div>";   
        echo"</a>"; 
}
//continue
}else{
echo "No Results";
}
?>
```

Comment: When emitting the results to the page, check for some indicator on the record of whether or not you want to style it differently.  If that indicator exists, emit a different style for that record.  In your database results, how can you tell the difference between the two records?

Comment: Holy SQL Injection batman! Don't take user input and directly place it into a SQL statement without escaping it or (preferably) using bind parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your table schema are too identical to easily tell the difference.  You can add a custom column to the query to distinguish them.  Something like:

```
<?php
$search = $_GET['s'];
$db = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "") or die ("could not connect to mysql");

if ($search) {
    $sql = "SELECT photos.*, 'photos' AS 'tableName' FROM photos
            WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%'
            ORDER BY id DESC";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT photos.*, 'photos' AS 'tableName' FROM photos
            UNION SELECT sponsor.*, 'sponsor' AS 'tableName' FROM sponsor
            ORDER BY id DESC";
}

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >=1) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo"<a class=\"{$row['tableName']}\" href=".$row['link'].">";
        echo"<div class='img_div'>";
        echo"<div class='white'><img src='images/".$row['image']."'></div>";
        echo"<h2>".$row['title']."</h2>";
        echo"<div class='date'>".$date = date('j F, Y', strtotime($row['date']))."</div>";
        echo"</div>";   
        echo"</a>"; 
}
//continue
}else{
echo "No Results";
}
?>
```

Notice in the queries, I've added `'photos' AS 'tableName'` and `'sponsors' AS 'tableName'` so that each query also adds a column with what table it was from.  That lets you access `row['tableName']` in the same way that you would reference any other column.

At that point it is as simple as adding a class to the `a` tag.  You could put that class on any of your elements depending on exactly how you want your markup.

**Keep in mind, this code as written is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection).  You should be using [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988867/when-should-i-use-prepared-statements) rather than directly inserting `GET` variables into your query.**

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use your suggestion in the update above, could you take a look thanks.