# form in html and php not showing up on the screen

Tags: php, html

I am writing out a form in php,html... witch should normally update to my database but the form isnt showing up on the screen. Help!!! I am not a very expirianced coder so pleases if you could tell meif there is any other probleme with my code. Thanks :-)

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>help</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php

            if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
                $dbhost = 'localhost';
                $dbuser = '*********';
                $dbpass = '*****';
                $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
                if(! $conn ) {
                   die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
                }
                $Userid = $_POST['UserID'];
                $TableID = $_POST['tableID'];
                $Life_points = $_POST['Life_points'];
                $xp_points = $_POST['xp_points'];
                $sql = "UPDATE points SET TableID = " . $TableID . " WHERE UserID = ". $Userid . " AND life_points = " . $Life_points . " AND xp_points= " . $xp_points;
                mysqli_select_db('womath');

                $retval = mysqli_query(  $conn, $sql );
                <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SERVER'] ?>            

                if(! $retval ) {
                    die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
                }
                echo "Updated data successfully\n";
                mysqli_close($conn);
                } else {
                ?>
                    <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
                        <table width = "400" border =" 0" cellspacing = "1" cellpadding = "2">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "100">UserID</td>
                                <td><input name = "UserID" type = "number" id = "UserID"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "100">TableID</td>
                                <td><input name = "TableID" type = "number" id = "TableID"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "100">life_points</td>
                                <td><input name = "life_points" type = "number" id = "life_points"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                               <td width = "100">xp_points</td>
                               <td><input name = "xp_points" type = "number" id = "xp_points"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "100"> </td>
                                <td> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "100"> </td>
                                <td><input name = "update" type = "submit" id = "update" value = "Update"></td>
                            </tr>
                       </table>
                   </form>
               <?php 
            } 
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please learn about prepared statements and use them. always.

Comment: @Tschallacka what is a prepared statement???

Comment: What is the error that you have getting ?

Comment: <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SERVER'] ?> when you have already declared your writing in PHP? Remove the <?php and ?> !!

Comment: @AnwenEvans http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988867/when-should-i-use-prepared-statements/24989031

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have issued a query to the database for compilation and execution before you have told MYSQL which database you are trying to gain access to.

The `mysqli_select_db('womath');` must happen before your first query

In fact that function is more for use when you want to switch from one database to another during a scripts execution, you can add the database name to the

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

like this

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,'womath');
```

line if you like and forget about the line

```
mysqli_select_db('womath');
```

completely.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>help</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    ini_set('log_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
     if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = '*********';
        $dbpass = '*****';

        $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,'womath');
                            // --------------------------^^^^^^^^
        if(! $conn ) {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
        }
        // move this calll to here or add database to the connect line
        //mysqli_select_db('womath');

        $Userid = $_POST['UserID'];
        $TableID = $_POST['tableID'];
        $Life_points = $_POST['Life_points'];
        $xp_points = $_POST['xp_points'];

        $sql = "UPDATE points SET TableID = '$TableID'
                WHERE UserID = '$Userid' 
                  AND life_points = '$Life_points' 
                  AND xp_points = '$xp_points'";

        $retval = mysqli_query(  $conn, $sql );

        // this following line also need a `;`
        echo $_SERVER['PHP_SERVER'];

        if(! $retval ) {
           die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
        }
        echo "Updated data successfully\n";

        mysqli_close($conn);

    // remove this else, as with it in place
    // you only show the form when you are NOT updating the database
    // }else {
    // just terminate the IF so the form will show after an update
    // AND when page is first loaded and there is no user input
    }
?>
           <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
              <table width = "400" border =" 0" cellspacing = "1" 
                 cellpadding = "2">

                <tr>
                    <td width = "100">UserID</td>
                    <td><input name = "UserID" type = "number" 
                       id = "UserID"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width = "100">TableID</td>
                    <td><input name = "TableID" type = "number" id = "TableID"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width = "100">life_points</td>
                    <td><input name = "life_points" type = "number" id = "life_points"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width = "100">xp_points</td>
                    <td><input name = "xp_points" type = "number" id = "xp_points"></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100"> </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100"> </td>
                    <td>
                       <input name = "update" type = "submit" id = "update" value = "Update">
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
           </form>
  <?php
     }
  ?>
```

Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Maybe one or more of your columns are defined as some sort of  text datatype.

Comment: For it to say could not update data I had to take away  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SERVER']

Comment: Had to take away what?

Comment: When you say terminate the IF how do I do that?

Comment: I have done what you have asked but it is now showing 
HTTP 500 error
That’s odd... the website can’t display this page
The site may be under maintenance or could have a programming error.

Comment: Can you check the error log, or add the 4 new lines I added after the `<?php`

Comment: https://anwen.000webhostapp.com/new/index.php      here is a link to what It is showing now.@RiggsFolly

Comment: And is there anything in the PHP Error log?