# How to combine SQL query with a PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, merge

I have this query to count the number of forms that are submitted by a certain user

```
$sql="SELECT `ID` FROM `kform` WHERE `ID`='$ID'";                               
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$k=0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                                                                                                 
      $k++;
   }
}
```

plus I have this php script that is basically check a certain date (which is included in each form) and prints **valid** if it is within this fiscal year

```
$endYear = 2017;
while($endYear <= 2025) {
    $end = $endYear.'/06/30';
    $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $end);
    $initDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $end);
    $initDate = $initDate->sub(new DateInterval('P1Y')) -> add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $ddb =  $row2['Date'];
    $dateFromDB = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $ddb);
    if ($dateFromDB >= $initDate && $dateFromDB <= $endDate) { 
        echo "valid\n";
        echo "\tStartDate->\"".$initDate->format("Y-m-d")."\"\n";
        echo "\tEndDate->\"".$endDate->format("Y-m-d")."\"\n";
        echo "\tDateFromDatabase->\"".$dateFromDB->format("Y-m-d")."\"\n";
    }

    $endYear++;
}
```

Now what I was trying to do is to combine these two functions together, the idea behind that is to **count** only the forms that are in this fiscal year, **any older forms should not be counted**. I tried different ways to combine them but it gave me different errors every time, So is it even possible to do so?

Comment: Did my best to make the example code readable, with the block structure visible and some spaces around things like >= so that you can see the intention more clearly.

Also made use of {} consistent, starting on same line as if/while etc. not sometimes one place and sometimes another.

Comment: When... WHEN will people learn they should use prepared statements. Where does all this outdated and horribly secure code examples originate from? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988867/when-should-i-use-prepared-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go on from that:

```
 function isValidYear($dategiven){
   $endYear=2017;
   while($endYear<=2025) {
     $end = $endYear.'/06/30';
     $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $end);
     $initDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $end);
     $initDate = $initDate->sub(new DateInterval('P1Y'))->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
     $ddb =  $dategiven;
     $dateFromDB = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $ddb);
     if ($dateFromDB>=$initDate && $dateFromDB<=$endDate) { 
       return true;
     }
     $endYear++;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

And

```
$sql="SELECT `ID` FROM `kform` WHERE `ID`='$ID'";                               
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$k=0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   if(isValidYear($row['datefield'])){
      $k++;
   }
}
```

Note: Your `$sql` selects only the `ID` field. You have to at `Date`

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `kform` WHERE `ID`='$ID'";
```

Comment: it works! thank you so much, i can use `$dategiven` in `'datefield'`, right?

Comment: and `isValidDate` isn't supposed to be `isValidYear`?

Comment: You have to set up `'datefield'` to the right field from your database ( you have used `$row2['Date']`). and yes `isValidYear` is better i change it now. But you can call it like you want.