# Appending NULL to a string, used for MySQL insert query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a new entry to a MySQL database, with last 5 parameters being optional, so NULL value is possible. I am having trouble appending NULL value to a query string, based on received POST data.

How to append NULL value to a query string?

```
//more similar mysqli_real_escape_string rows and if clauses above these lines
$phonenumber=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["phonenumber"]);
$gender = NULL;
if($_POST["gender"] != null)
   $gender=(int)mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["gender"]);
$age = NULL;
if($_POST["age"] != null)
   $age = (int)mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["age"]);
$qs_registration="insert into uporabnik (ID, up_ime, geslo, email, ime, priimek, naslov_bivanja, posta_foreign_key,
tel_stevilka, spol, starost) VALUES (NULL, '".$username."','".$password."','".$email."','".$name."',
'".$surname."','".$location."',".$postoffice.",'".$phonenumber."',".$gender.",".$age.")";
```

Comment: You can set the default value to `NULL` in MySQL, then just leave those fields out when inserting if those values aren't present; building your query dynamically.

Comment: Table design is bad, ID field should not be null, either auto increment or specify a value in the insert statement

Comment: @glant If `ID` is the primary key, with auto-increment, passing NULL would just make it use the AI, so that could work if its set up right.

Comment: @Qirel that's my point...Is the ID a pKey or just a column ?? Not sure in this case

Comment: We don't know here, but it can be perfectly valid as-is, likely the ID is an auto-increment - then it works ;-)

Comment: If it was declared as PKey in the designer it would show as null not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need  a null value eg: are using and auto_increment  id ..in a column  then you could omit the related  values  (and you can avoid the string concat  because '$yourvar' is enough)

```
    "insert into uporabnik (up_ime, geslo, email, ime, priimek, 
      naslov_bivanja, posta_foreign_key, tel_stevilka, spol, starost)
    VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$name',
         '$surname','$location', $postoffice','$phonenumber',$gender,$age.")";
```

anyway be careful passing var you should eval a paramaetrized  query instead passing var for avoid sqlinjection

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be using prepared statements - [When should I use prepared statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988867/when-should-i-use-prepared-statements)

However, if you are just looking for an answer, just set your initial variables to the string `'NULL'` instead.

That way, when you concat everything, you'll get a query string that MySQL can understand:

```
$age = 'NULL';
if($_POST["age"] != null) {
    // Wrap each variable in quotes
   $age = "'" . (int)mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["age"]) . "'";
}
// etc.

$qs_registration="insert into uporabnik (ID, up_ime, geslo, email, ime, priimek, naslov_bivanja, posta_foreign_key,
tel_stevilka, spol, starost) VALUES (NULL, " . $username . "," . $password . "," . $email . "," . $name . ",
" . $surname . "," . $location . "," . $postoffice . "," . $phonenumber . "," . $gender . "," . $age . ")";
```

**NOTE**: I think there are a lot of other problems here, from not using prepared statements (as mentioned before) to how you have the table configured in the first place. But this should fix your issue at hand.

Comment: What if the variable is a string, then you need singlequotes around it in the query, and then you'd get `'NULL'` as a string, not actual *null*. And since your query has no singlequotes around the variables, it will fail.

Comment: A solution is to do `$age = $_POST["age"] != null ? "'".(int)mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["age"])."'" : NULL;`, then you'd get the sniglequote only when there is a value (albeit, this is a bad example, because age here is an integer, not a string - but its an example) ;-)