# Problems about keep in the page with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a form. My objective is send and insert the values of the form to my database. Then

1. Clear the input of the form
2. Show the successful message.
   Like this:

### [image]

[image]

My problems:When I press the "save" button, I am redirected to another page.

This is the operating error:

[image]

and change the page

[image]

¿What is the problem on my code?

html

```
<html>
<head><title>Insert Data Into MySQL: jQuery + AJAX + PHP</title></head>
<body>

<form id="myForm" action="userInfo.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Age : <input type="text" name="age" /><br />
<button type="submit" id="sub">Save</button>
</form>

<span id="result"></span>

 <script src="script/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/elscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</body>
</html
```

This is my script

```
$("#myForm").submit( function(e) {

// Prevent the normal form submission event
e.preventDefault();

// Create an object of the form
var form = $(this);

// Make an AJAX request
$.post(this.action, form.serializeArray(), function(info) {

    // Clear the form
    form[0].reset();

    // Display message
    $("#result").html(info); 

});
```

});

Finally, my code to insert

```
   <?php 
        $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        $db   = mysql_select_db('practicas');

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];

        if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO ajaxtabla VALUES('$name', '$age')"))
      echo "Successfully Inserted";
    else
      echo "Insertion Failed";
 ?>
```

Thanks for help me

Comment: mysql_ is long dead, use [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) -- or better [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). And learn about [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748357/1022914) and [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988867/when-should-i-use-prepared-statements/24989031).

Comment: sorry Mikey, in my university they don't teach us anything about all this. I have to search things to do my homeworks. for that reason I do not understand anything, my colleagues and me, have a bad programming base

Comment: did you include your scripts files correctly?

Comment: What do you mean??

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code by having just one event handler for when you submit the form. Additionally, you need to include `e.preventDefault()` which prevents the normal function of the submit button.

```
$("#myForm").submit( function(e) {

    // Prevent the normal form submission event
    e.preventDefault();

    // Create an object of the form
    var form = $(this);

    // Make an AJAX request
    $.post(this.action, form.serializeArray(), function(info) {

        // Clear the form
        form[0].reset();

        // Display message
        $("#result").html(info); 

    });

});
```

Give your button a `type` attribute as well to ensure your form submits upon clicking.

```
<button type="submit" id="sub">Save</button>
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {

    // Prevent the normal form submission event
    e.preventDefault();
    
    console.log('onsubmit event handler triggered');

    // Create an object of the form
    var form = $(this);

    // Make an AJAX request
    /*$.post(this.action, form.serializeArray(), function(info) {

      // Clear the form
      form[0].reset();

      // Display message
      $("#result").html(info);

    });*/
    
    // fake AJAX request
    setTimeout(function(){
       // Clear the form
      form[0].reset();
      // Display message
      $("#result").html('Successfully Inserted');
    }, 3000);
  });

});
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="userInfo.php" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br /> Age : <input type="text" name="age" /><br />
  <button type="submit" id="sub">Save</button>
</form>

<span id="result"></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks!! but it does not keep me on the page, it keeps changing :(

Comment: sorry Mikey, i am a bad programmer, but it does not work. I change my code in the question, can you see it? thanks for help me

Comment: @Vidal Open up your [browser's developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools), check the console and see if you have any errors. You should only be using *one* jQuery script and it needs to be placed *before* your script.

Comment: okeey. My console say that i have problem here: `GET http://localhost/PracticaAjax/script/elscript.js net::ERR_ABORTED` is this important?

Comment: @Vidal Of course. It means it can't find your script. Paste the URL in your browser and see if it loads. If it can't, figure out why that is e.g. wrong filename, wrong location etc.

Comment: it does not matter, I leave it, I search other things, thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

In ajax you are posting the form with its action so it will be redirected confirm
If you don't want to redirect then send ajax request like this

```
$.ajax({
method:post,
url:"File name you want to send request"

}).done(function(response){

});
```