# Comparing date from variable to MySQL date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm comparing date specified in PHP with dates in MySQL table and then echoing all rows with dates after the date in PHP. It works OK when I specify the date in the SELECT command, but when I make it a variable it doesn't work.

My PHP is:

```
  $sql = "SELECT event FROM LifeEvents WHERE event_date > '1995-02-27'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo $row["event"] . "<br>";
      }
  } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
  $conn->close();
```

This works ok. But when I replace the SELECT with:

```
SELECT event FROM LifeEvents WHERE event_date > $date
```

It no longer works. 
For the variable I've tried working with both:

```
$date = new DateTime('1995-02-27')
```

and

```
$date = '1995-02-27'
```

Neither of them works. The data type in MySQL is DATE.

Comment: is that variable dynamic ? I mean the script changes it or you just put a date in it as you mentioned above ?

Comment: @ths Right now, I just put a date in it, but in final version of the code the date in the variable will be taken from another db table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets create a variable that holds a date and then convert it to date format that MySQL can understand.

```
$dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('1995-02-27')); // maybe filled dynamically
 $sql = "SELECT event FROM LifeEvents WHERE event_date > '$dt'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo $row["event"] . "<br>";
      }
  } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
  $conn->close();
```

Then change what you want in order to serve your needs.
Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 3):

For the string variable

```
$date = '1995-02-27'
$sql = "SELECT event FROM LifeEvents WHERE event_date > '$date'";
// this should work exactly as
$sql = "SELECT event FROM LifeEvents WHERE event_date > '1995-02-27'";
```

For the `DateTime` object, this should work

```
$date = new DateTime('1995-02-27')
$sql = "SELECT event FROM LifeEvents WHERE event_date > '" . $date->format(Y-m-d). "'";
```

I suggest you **always** set the timezone when you are dealing with dates and times because underestimate timezones can result in really bad bugs specially if your applications is dealing with many timezones and you have `timestamp` data type in your database.

make it a habit to do this

```
define('DEFAULT_TIMEZONE','UTC');//set this in your global config.php file
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone(DEFAULT_TIMEZONE));
```

Comment: Personally I thought this was a much better answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `'1995-02-27'` and `DateTime('1995-02-27')` are both not valid in that case :

1. `'1995-02-27'` would work if you'd have put extra quotes around `$date` in your SQL query :
    `"SELECT event FROM LifeEvents WHERE event_date > '$date'"`
2. `DateTime('1995-02-27')` doesn't have a `__toString()` magic method so PHP is unable to represent it as a string.
    You have to use the `format` method : `$date = $date->format('Y-m-d')` (and it will still miss the quotes)

One or another solution, [you need to protect yourself against SQL injections using prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988867/when-should-i-use-prepared-statements/24989031)! And you will actually no longer need any quote.

Answer (score -2):

Try using the [Carbon librar](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)y for PHP.

Store a date with PHP:

```
$current_time = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
```

Then just compare it the same way.

Comment: PHP already has functions to deal with date and time there is no reason to import a new library.