# How to pass an javascript array to an php script

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have a normal html table filled with database entries.
I got a plugin to select multiple rows in this table.
Now i want to click on a button and delete the database entry so I need to get the id out of the array and but it in my php script.
But I have not really an idea how to do it.

```
</div>


   <table id="myTable" class="content-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Artikelnummer</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Preis</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM artikel;";
          $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

          if ($resultCheck > 0) {
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                ?> 
                <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $row["id"]?></td> <?php 
                ?> <td> <?php echo $row["artikelnummer"]?></td> <?php 
                ?> <td> <?php echo $row["name"]?></td> <?php 
                ?> <td> <?php echo $row["preis"]?> €</td> </tr><?php 
              }
          }

         ?>

    </tbody>
  </table> 
  </div>
```

```
var $rows = [];
    $(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
        // start plugin
        $('#myTable').TableSelection({
                sort : true, // sort or not (true | false)
                status : 'multiple', // single or multiple selection (default is 'single')
            }, function(obj){ // callback function return selected rows array
                $rows = obj.rows;
        });

    });
```

```php
<?php
    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

    $artid = ???;

    $sql = "DELETE FROM artikel WHERE id= $artid;";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    header("Location: ../index.php?daten=success");
```

Comment: Multiple ways of doing this but all stem from sending the `$artid` as a request variable.

Comment: Btw your sql code is at risk of sql injection, have a read of [When should I use prepared statments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988867/when-should-i-use-prepared-statements/24989031)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with html attributes. I make a example for you with html, css and javascript.

this is your html.

```html
<table id="tableSelected" class="content-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Artikelnummer</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Preis</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-id="1">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1-1</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-id="2">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2-1</td>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

as you can see, every "tr" tag has "data-id" attribute.

```
var $rows = [];
    $(function() {
      $('#tableSelected').TableSelection({
        sort : true,
        status : 'multiple',
      }, function(obj) {
        $.each(obj.rows, function(i, row){
          var id = $('#tableSelected').RowValue(row).attr('data-id') // You can get id with this code
        });
      });
    });
```

Note: https://codepen.io/yusufilkeroguz/pen/vqPgzZ you can see live preview from here :)

Comment: You can send "id" with ajax to php. in js after id, add ajax, example url https://foo.com/bar/delete?id=[SELECTED-ID]

(this is get method, if you want you can send with post).

in php, 

$artid = $_GET['id'];

....