# SQL problem Unknown column 'approved' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

im beginner i cant find a solution with that message when i use debug mod on my script

```
Unknown column 'approved' in 'where clause' | QUERY: SELECT COUNT(`record_num`) AS `count` FROM `scraper_import` WHERE `approved` = 1
```

my scraper.php

```
$i = trim($i);
if (dbQuery("INSERT INTO scraper_import (url, user, paysite) VALUES ('$i','$_POST[submitter]', '$_POST[paysite]')")) {
   $counter++;
 } else {
   $errors++;
 }
            }
        }
    }
```

I need create column approved

Comment: there is no column `approved` in the attached image.

Comment: Your script is at risk for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/). Use [prepared statements](https://bobby-tables.com/php). Even [escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/) the string is not safe!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use prepared statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988867/when-should-i-use-prepared-statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need create column approved

In PHPMyAdmin You can add something like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `scaper_import` ADD COLUMN `approved` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

That should add the column you desire.

Comment: Hi thanks for help me but im real beginner can u give me a code for Sql file to import

Comment: I add approuved now its work thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I add on my sql file column `approved` and data and now it works. Thanks for helping me.

This is the solution:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scraper_import` (
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `paysite` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `approved` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `record_num` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`record_num`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```