# Why everytime I refresh the page a new sesssion is getting posted in the database?

Tags: php

what my code does now is its posting the session in the database and everytime I refresh this page it keeps posting the same session again and again. I don't get why? The solution is probably a simple one but I tried everything. Hope to get some help.

```
<?php
session_start();


require '../../required/connection.php';
require '../../required/functions.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['alive']))
{
    $id = $_GET['trxid'];
    $_SESSION['alive'] = uniqid();
    $currentSession = $_SESSION['alive'];
    $checkQuery = "SELECT token FROM request_data WHERE token='$currentSession'";
    $checkResult = mysqli_query($con, $checkQuery);
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($checkResult);
    if($row < 1)
    {
        $firstQuery = "INSERT INTO request_data (token, link) VALUES ('$currentSession', '$id')";
        $firstResult = mysqli_query($con, $firstQuery);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please note that this code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection), since you're getting the raw trxid from the query and aren't escaping it. You should use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24989031/886926).

Comment: @ErikTerwan Yes I know normally I use prepared statements. I just want to know this so I can go on this was just a simple problem for myself

Comment: What do you get if you do a var_dump of $_SESSION between the require lines and the if block?

Answer (score 0):

I think that something went wrong in your `connection.php` or `functions.php`. Is it also possible that you have server errors that lead to this behavior? Further it could be that you have modified the [configurations of sessions in the php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/de/session.configuration.php) (for example the lifetime)?

The following example is based on your code and works on the page [phpfiddle.org](https://phpfiddle.org/lite)

```php
<?php
session_start();

// just for testing - you can comment it in and out
//$_SESSION['alive'] = null;

if (!isset($_SESSION['alive'])) {
    echo 'FALSE; <br/>';
    $_SESSION['alive'] = uniqid();
    echo 'AFTER = "'. $_SESSION['alive'] . '"'; 
} else {
    echo 'TRUE = "'. $_SESSION['alive'] . '"'; 
}
?>
```