# why my database is not getting selected when i m writing this query?

Tags: mysql

```
$sql_query =  "INSERT INTO `vip_tours'.'trip` ( `name`, `email`, `age`, `phone`, `gender`, `description`, `date_time`) VALUES ( '$name', '$email', '$age', '$number', '$gender', '$desc', current_timestamp());";
```

Comment: do you get an error? Also, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24989031/14401587

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? Check your mysql connection for db name. Is it same as vip_tours ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your query.

```
`vip_tours'.'trip`
```

should be:

```
`vip_tours`.`trip`
```